# Add a label on a gmail message instead of thread

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have an app script and I want to add a label to a single message instead of the entire thread.

```js
const thread = threads[i];
      const id = thread.getId();
      if (emailsId.indexOf(id) == -1) {
        const messages = thread.getMessages();
        let emailSent = false;

        for (let j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
          if (emailSent) {
            break;
          }
          const message = messages[0];
          const attachments = message.getAttachments();
          message.forward(emailTo, attachments);
          emailSent = true;

          const messageLabel = createNestedGmailLabel(label);
          thread.addLabel(messageLabel); // add label to message, instead of thread
          thread.markRead();
          thread.moveToArchive();   
          [...]
```

When I disable conversational view in Gmail, I can add a label, archive mail, etc. for each individual mail. However, I am unsure if this is possible in App Script.